# in dplyr select with a drop does not work

Tags: r, select, dplyr

In dplyr, I want to exclude columns which contain the word "junk"
but, there may not be any column that contain the word "junk". In that case, dplyr should return all columns. But it returns none.
See unit test case below.

```
df<-data.frame(name=paste("name",1:5), age=1:5)
str(df)
# 'data.frame': 5 obs. of  2 variables:
# $ name: Factor w/ 5 levels "name 1","name 2",..: 1 2 3 4 5
# $ age : int  1 2 3 4 5
df1<-df%>%select(-contains("junk"))
str(df1)
# 'data.frame': 5 obs. of  0 variables
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Note that this works fine, if at least one column had that condition> df<-data.frame(name=paste("name",1:5), agejunk=1:5)
> df1<-df%>%select(-contains("junk"))
> str(df1)
'data.frame': 5 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ name: Factor w/ 5 levels "name 1","name 2",..: 1 2 3 4 5

Comment: I thought something like `df %>% select(ifelse(sum(grepl("junk",names(df)))>0,
                            -contains("junk"),
                            everything()))` would work, but `everything()` doesn't appear to return everything...

Comment: and a similar story with `df %>% select(-matches("*junk*"))`

Answer (score 19):

It works if you put `everything()` before the `-contains()` inside `select`:

```
library(dplyr) # 0.4.1
df %>% select(everything(), -contains("junk"))
#    name age
#1 name 1   1
#2 name 2   2
#3 name 3   3
#4 name 4   4
#5 name 5   5
```

However, I agree that it would be more intuitive if it worked without the need for `everything()`.

Comment: I can't find `everything` in 0.4.1. Are you using the devel version?

Comment: @DavidArenburg, it is mentioned under `?select`  in the "special functions" section in 0.4.1

Comment: Oh this is one of these functions that can be called only inside `select`

Comment: @DavidArenburg - it should probably be aliased to `?select` so that one can do `?contains`

Answer (score 9):

**Edit:** This has been fixed in the newest version of `dplyr`. See also [here](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/commit/4ab2f0e43833f78aa86b7047344a56a4d556a104).

**Original post:** Just for completeness, here is the reason for this bug. The function `contains` is internally using `grep("junk", names(df))`. Of course this returns `integer(0)`.

```
dplyr:::contains(names(df), "junk")
## integer(0)
```

Now `-integer(0)` is of course the same as `+integer(0)` and calling `select(df, integer(0))` clearly returns a data frame with 0 columns.

```
select(df, integer(0))
## data frame with 0 columns and 5 rows
```

Answer (score 5):

This works, but it's not pretty

```
df %>% select(which(!(names(.) %in% grep("junk", names(.), value=T))))
```

Comment: I think the problem might be that the OP have partial matches for `junk`

Comment: It gave me the same problem as indicated by OP when there are no junk columns

Comment: It does work, but this might be a bit longer than using a standalone `grep`

Comment: `df[!grepl('junk', names(df))]` is simple in these cases.  I just wonder whether this is a bug in `select` or not. Plus one for consistently trying to get a correct answer

Comment: @6pool You can open an issue (or the OP) at https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues

Comment: `df %>% select(which(!grepl("junk",names(df))))` will work in dplyr as you need integer positions. This seems to definitely be a bug though.